# Multiple UITextField: textFieldShouldBeginEditing: / textFieldDidEndEditing: Ordering

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I've multiple **`UITextField`** in an **`UIView`**. I change the view layout before the user start editing the fields using *`textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`* and then restore it via *`textFieldDidEndEditing:`*.

e.g.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    // Change UIView layout
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    // Restore UIView layout
}
```

However, if I clicked on another **`UITextField`** while editing an **`UITextField`**, the execution order would be:

1. Another **`UITextField`**'s *`textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`*.
2. Current **`UITextField`**'s *`textFieldDidEndEditing:`*.

aka console log:

```
textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

In this case, the **`UIView`** layout setting would be incorrect. I also tried *`textFieldShouldEndEditing:`* but didn't change the ordering.

If I added KVO style observers to the **`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`** / **`UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`**, the order will be:

```
textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
keyboardWillShow:
textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
textFieldDidEndEditing:
keyboardWillShow:
```

Then I can do what needs to be done within `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` in `keyboardWillShow:`. But since I cant get current **`UITextField`** as in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:`, I won't be able to do necessary updates correctly.

I know I can setup another variable to track current editing status, but are there better ways to make sure one **`UITextField`** did end editing before it get switched?

Comment: have you tried adding observer? like keyboardWillShow and KeyboardWillHide

Comment: First responder may help you get the current text field?

Comment: @zcui93 I did check them using `isFirstResponder` for both textFields. Seems they were both not when `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is called, so can't do what I wanted.

Comment: Check them in keyboard notification method? After textField ends editing, they are not first responder anymore.

Comment: @zcui93 yes I already did that, also with comparing delegate's textField object with my 2 textFields to have the correct UI layout. But if I have lots of textFields, doing this alone won't be possible. I'm hoping there's a more universal way to do this.

Comment: I just wonder, what if you save current first responder on each "begin editing" and call resignFirstResponder on previous one if set. This way you could probably force "end editing" to be called immediately from within "begin editing".

Comment: It could have worked, the only problem is that it'll have to dismiss the keyboard and then show it again between the switches.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried assigning a tag to your text fields and then basing your logic on that?

```
UITextField *yourTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:result];
```

Comment: You suggested that I use the tag to trace current textField? That could help when there were lots of fields, but still need an extra variable to do the trace and with KVO. I'll give you an up vote for the input, but will leave the question open to see if there were better solutions. Thank you.